# Highcharts pie chart slice animation only works when an error is thrown

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, highcharts

I have this function that translates a slice of a pie chart radially out from the center to highlight it on mouseover and then returns it to its original position on mouseout:

```
           function setTranslation(p, slice) {
                p.sliced = slice;
                if (p.sliced) {
                    p.graphic.animate(p.slicedTranslation);
                } else {
                    p.graphic.animate({
                        translateX: 0,
                        translateY: 0});
                }
            }
```

I call it on the Highcharts config object on the point mouseover and mouseout events like this:

```
    mouseOver: function () {
         setTranslation(this, true);
    },
    mouseOut: function () {
        setTranslation(this, false);
    }
```

It works perfectly, unless the window is resized, on my application I don't think the user would resize it much, but I have exporting enabled and in Chrome the download bar pops-up and triggers a window resize, after which the animation stops working, the translation is done but not smoothly, it's done instantly.

After playing with the code I found out that if I have a window resize event handler with jQuery that throws any error the animation keeps working after the resize, and the rest of the page doesn't break, so I have this patch:

```
$(window).resize(function (e) {
     throw new Error("Intentional error")
});
```

I think that when the window is resized some parameter that the graphic.animate uses is changed and it stops working, and when an error is thrown somehow that doesn't happen. I think this is not normal and throwing errors intentionally isn't good, but I don't know how to check what the resize event is changing.

Comment: Is this "slice radially out from the center" similar to the built in slice functionality? If it is, why not use it and avoid these issues? If not, what specific differences are there that you require?

Comment: @Ondkloss The default slice functionality is on click, I have a custom drilldown function that uses that click handler so I disabled the default slicing and added this custom on mouseover and mouseout. I'm using a modified Highcharts library on a propietary design extension, hence there are some slight differences with the Highcharts usage and also it's not the most recent version of Highcharts.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you are using drilldown, but take a look at this example. Is this not usable? [JSFiddle mouseOver/mouseOut slice](http://jsfiddle.net/hpnm52t9/)

Comment: It bugs out, two or more slices happen or they stay sliced even on mouseOut.

Comment: I was kind of sloppy with coding it. Even when using `slice(boolean)` instead of just `slice()`? Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpnm52t9/1/). Tried a bit myself, but wasn't able to bug it out.

Comment: That solved the issue.. thanks. The Highcharts API is not very clear on it, at least on the documentation for the pie chart options, that function is in the documentation for the point element.. Weird. So how do I give you credit for answering my question?

Comment: Good to hear that it solved your issue! I will write an answer that is a bit more precise for other readers and submit it, so you can accept that if you still agree :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually handling the slicing with translation you can reuse the built in slice functionality with the `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events to prevent any edge cases, such as the one you are experiencing.

The following code will slice on `mouseOver` and remove the slice on `mouseOut` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpnm52t9/1/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function(event) {
                    this.slice(true);
                },
                mouseOut: function(event) {
                    this.slice(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not affected by window resizing, and quite tidy.

For pie charts specifically each slice is a `Point` in a single `Series`, which is why these events are under `pie.point.events`.